# Using UFW GUI on my Ubuntu Apache VM

Tags: apache-2.2

I want to block all incoming ports on my Apache VM.  When I think I have the setting correct I try to access the Apache VM session from another Ubuntu session and I can still get through.  The IP on my Apache VM session is 192.168.254.30:80.  Like I said when I enter that IP with port number in a browser in another Ubuntu session I can still get through. What am I doing wrong?